# How to get last inserted value for a non identity column in DB2

Tags: db2

There is an eficient way in DB2 to get the last inserted value for a column that is not an identity in DB2, without order or fetch??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select ... from final table ( insert into ... )` 
if your Db2-version and Db2-platform supports this syntax.
Example in the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_selectvalueinsert.html).